# how to set count(*) as field name in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am using larvel eloquent. 
i am using this query using model. My code is

```
$books = Book::select('title', 'author', Book::raw('count(*) as copies'))
              ->where('title', 'like', '%'.$name.'%')
              ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($name) {
                $query->where('author', 'like', '%'.$name.'%')
                      ->where('subject', 'like', '%'.$name.'%');
            })
            ->groupBy('title','author')
            ->get();
```

I got the error
**"strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given"**
I know the error is in **count(*)***. The code 
**raw('count() as copies')** is used in **table**.
But I dont know how to use **count(*) as copies** in model eloquent. My model name is **Book**.
One more doubt i have, can we use multple fields in groupBy, ie
**groupBy('title','author')**

Comment: Check if it works Book::select('title', 'author',  \DB::raw("count(*) as copies") )

Comment: You may pass multiple arguments to the groupBy method to group by multiple columns... Please go through the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Comment: You can also use `selectRaw()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `selectRaw()`

```
$books = Book::select('title', 'author'))
          ->where('title', 'like', '%'.$name.'%')
          ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($name) {
            $query->where('author', 'like', '%'.$name.'%')
                  ->where('subject', 'like', '%'.$name.'%');
        })
         ->selectRaw('count(*) as copies')
        ->groupBy('title','author')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, SelectRaw

```
$books = Book::select('title', 'author')
    ->selectRaw('count(*) as copies')
    ->where('title', 'like', '%'.$name.'%')
    ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($name) {
        $query->where('author', 'like', '%'.$name.'%')
            ->where('subject', 'like', '%'.$name.'%');
        })
    ->groupBy('title','author')
->get();
```

You have this posiblity also

```
->select('title','author', DB::raw('count(*) as copies'))
```

[Laravel Documentation Raw](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-expressions)

Comment: He does not have any `price` or `department` columns

Comment: Sorry...copy and paste

Comment: Yes it works. Saves lot of time. selectRaw('count(*) as copies')